# converting midi track to software instrument track in Logic Pro

Tags: midi, logic-pro

I have imported a Midi file into Logic Pro. Trying to change the tracks from midi tracks into software instrument tracks. When I select a software instrument, the music stops on the track and it goes into a recording mode.

What do i need to do to convert the track from a green midi track into something i can use software instruments instead without losing the recorded music?

Comment: Uncanny! I wanted to exactly this, but inside Cubase LE rather than Logic Pro

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know if you can actually change one type of track to another, my guess is you cannot but there is a much easier solution.

First start by doing a “save as” and change the name slightly so you still have a copy of the song in its original form. Then, simply create a new software instrument track and assign the sound you want to it. Once you do that click-hold the region with the MIDI information and drag it over to the software instrument track. You can also copy/paste or cut/paste as an option. The MIDI info should then play with whatever sound you assigned to the software instrument track. Repeat the process for any other tracks you have.

Comment: I guess it is the same if you CMD-a to select all, and then CMD-c to copy to clipboard, and then start a new software instrument project, and then paste it over there